# CSS border angle problem

Tags: css, border, angle

I am creating a menu with 4 different color borders. When viewed in Safari 5, the left and right borders go from top to bottom with no angles around the box. When viewed in FF 4, there is a border angle at the border-bottom and border-right elements. This makes the menu look different in different browsers. Here is the CSS for the menu item:

```
ul#mainnav a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #b0c9da;
   padding: 7px 7px 7px 14px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #01304f;
   border-top: 1px solid #1a74af;
   border-right: 1px solid #fff;
   border-left: 1px solid #246792; }
```

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: how different? Can you post a screenshot or something? Or maybe write a sample on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "border angle"? The CSS you provided has a 1px border. How can you have a 1 pixel angle? Attached is a screenshot I took of Safari 5 with a 5px border of the colors you provided. Looks like it has an angle to me: https://img.skitch.com/20110330-fb72iid4dqggx2gmpwbcfxd1a3.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the browsers' determination of where to begin the border line and where to end it. Unfortunately there is no fix for this. Your best bet is to pick border colors that are similar enough that they will not stand out so tremendously.

Another option, requiring modern browsers / CSS3 support, would be to use a box-shadow on the element. For example:

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,0,0,1), 
            inset 1px -1px 1px rgba(0,255,0,1);
```

You can add multiple layers of box shadows of only 1px width, and specify the direction that they "drop". Could be fun to play with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was just running into this problem and doing box-shadow worked like a charm.